# Simplify $\large{\frac{7x}{2x-1} +\frac{5x-2}{2x+2}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Simplify the rational expression.

$$\frac{7x}{2x-1} + \frac{5x-2}{2x+2}$$

My work:

\begin{eqnarray*} \frac{7x}{2x-1} + \frac{5x-2}{2x+2}
&=& \frac{7x(2x+2)+(5x-2)(2x-1)}{(2x-1)(2x+2)} \\ &=& \frac{7x(2x+2)+(5x-2)(2x-1)}{(2x-1)(2x+2)}.\end{eqnarray*}

Is this correct?

Comment: question is ==Simplify each rational expression.

Comment: Simplify??? You made it complex!

Comment: you have to expand the numerator and write it as a polynomial in standard form $ax^2+bx+c$

Comment: @NeilRoy: the simplicity of an expression depends on the context. If the next question is to find the sign of the expression in terms of $x$, then the simplification is what the OP is doing (after factoring the numerator). If the next question is to find the antiderivative, then simplify would probably mean "express as a sum of partial fractions".

Comment: @NeilRoy: However, I agree that without any context, the new form the OP will obtain doesn't seem simpler to me. Raw "simplify" questions are stupid.

Answer (score 2):

I think that it's more simple:
$$\frac{7x}{2x-1} + \frac{5x-2}{2x+2} = \frac72 + \frac{7x - \frac72(2x-1)}{2x-1} + \frac52 + \frac{5x-2-\frac52(2x+2)}{2x+2}=\\=
6 + \frac{7/2}{2x-1} + \frac{-7}{2x+2} = 6+\frac72\left(\frac{1}{2x-1}-\frac{1}{x+1}\right).
$$

Answer (score 1):

You would also have to check that nothing cancels from FOILing the quadratics.

Is $\frac{24x^2+5x+2}{4x^2+2x-2}$ simplifiable?

Answer (score 1):

\begin{eqnarray*} \frac{7x}{2x-1} + \frac{5x-2}{2x+2}
&=& \frac{7x(2x+2)+(5x-2)(2x-1)}{(2x-1)(2x+2)} \\ &=& \frac{7x(2x+2)+(5x-2)(2x-1)}{(2x-1)(2x+2)}\\ 
&=&\frac{14x^2+14x+10x^2-5x-4x+2}{(2x-1)(2x+2)} \\
&=& \frac{24x^2+5x+2}{(2x-1)(2x+2)}\end{eqnarray*}